Resize JPanel with animation
I want to make a panel that, when the mouse enters it, its height increases smoothly and when the mouse leaves it, its height decreases smoothly.
public class Main {
    private static final int INITIAL_HEIGHT = 150;
    private static final int TARGET_HEIGHT = 200;
    private static final int ANIMATION_DELAY = 10;
    private static final int INCREMENT = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, INITIAL_HEIGHT));
            panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

            frame.add(panel);
            frame.pack();

            panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    new Timer(ANIMATION_DELAY, new ActionListener() {
                        private int currentHeight = INITIAL_HEIGHT;

                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            if (currentHeight < TARGET_HEIGHT) {
                                currentHeight += INCREMENT;
                                panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, currentHeight));
                                panel.revalidate();
                                frame.pack();
                            } else {
                                ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    new Timer(ANIMATION_DELAY, new ActionListener() {
                        private int currentHeight = TARGET_HEIGHT;

                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            if (currentHeight > INITIAL_HEIGHT) {
                                currentHeight -= INCREMENT;
                                panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, currentHeight));
                                panel.revalidate();
                                frame.pack();
                            } else {
                                ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
            });
        });
    }
}

The problem is that if I move the mouse out of the panel while changing the size of the panel, it does not work properly.

Just cancel the former Timer.

Try to use only one timer and add a boolean to track the direction and make sure that the animation is happening in one direction
public class Main {
private static final int INITIAL_HEIGHT = 150;
private static final int TARGET_HEIGHT = 200;
private static final int ANIMATION_DELAY = 10;
private static final int INCREMENT = 2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(300, 300); // Adjust frame size to better see the effect

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, INITIAL_HEIGHT));
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Timer timer = new Timer(ANIMATION_DELAY, null);
        boolean growing = false;

        panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                if (!growing) {
                    growing = true;
                    timer.removeActionListener(timer.getActionListeners()[0]);
                    timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        private int currentHeight = panel.getPreferredSize().height;

                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            if (currentHeight < TARGET_HEIGHT) {
                                currentHeight += INCREMENT;
                                panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, currentHeight));
                                panel.revalidate();
                                frame.pack();
                            } else {
                                timer.stop();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    timer.start();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                if (growing) {
                    growing = false;
                    timer.removeActionListener(timer.getActionListeners()[0]);
                    timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        private int currentHeight = panel.getPreferredSize().height;

                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            if (currentHeight > INITIAL_HEIGHT) {
                                currentHeight -= INCREMENT;
                                panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, currentHeight));
                                panel.revalidate();
                                frame.pack();
                            } else {
                                timer.stop();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    timer.start();
                }
            }
        });
    });
}}

